# Where to store pictures taken from Android app

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am updating my application to adhere to the new M permissions.  This (which is good) got me thinking about where to store media, in this case pictures that are taken from within my app.

The 2 options that I am considering for storing photos:

1) Store in "app external"  ie, context.getExternalFilesDir(String type).

Pros:

- Seems good in that is seems Android has less warnings about storing
  here as at least you app gets its own space, and that space is not
  typically where users are storing there content.
- It also has a huge benefit in that for M, I don't have to ask for
  permission to write to this folder.  Meaning that when user takes a
  pic I don't have to ask for Camera and External write permissions.

Cons:

- Files are not auto scanned by media scanner.
- Files maybe be harder for user to find if they need to pull from the device.

2) Store in "public external" ie, context. getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type). Obviously pros/cons are just switched from above.

With that it seems like the 'right' place to store photos is in app external.  However a lot of 'common' apps I have tested, like twitter and facebook choose to store media in public external.  Which starts to lead me to believe that maybe I am missing something.

So my question is this. Is there anything I am not thinking about with regards on where to store media?

Comment: This seems like a pretty subjective question without a discrete answer!  How do I formulate an answer that you will accept?  :-)

Comment: The main question is-  do you want the pictures taken to be found by media scanner and usable by other apps later?  If so, use public storage.  If not, use app private storage.  That question is really up to the app author.

Comment: @DougStevenson agree :) But I thought I would ask anyways and risk being shamed.  Also really more so the question is not which one to pick, but did I miss anything glaring.   Again probably hard to 'correctly' answer.  I apologize.

Comment: @GabeSechan don't care much about other apps using the media.  I do care about the media scanner, but I can programmatically do that.  I also care about a user possibly getting the media off the device if they want.  But I think app external is a common enough place that most users would be able to find my apps folder.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Let me explain :

- first storing data in "app external" is a good practice when this data is really private and you don't want other apps to access it,
- "app external" is not recommended in some cases :

> As such, you should not use these directories for media that ultimately belongs to the user, such as photos captured or edited with your app, or music the user has purchased with your app—those files should be saved in the public directories([docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles)).

- you shouldn't go for "public external" if your app is very dependent on the data you're storing (it could be missing, not mounted etc.).

I don't really know your use case but in general i will probably go for a mix.